# Building a moon base - cost, weight, and rocket to send pressure vessel

Tags: the-moon, lunar-base

I am trying to validate the following hypothesis in order to simulate the building of a base on the moon (I am starting a [video game project](https://outerspaceshack.com/) ) , I am asking with current technology:

- What would be the approximate weight of a 4mx7m pressure vessel of cylinder shape to be used as a building block for a base ? I calculate around 3 tons based on the weight of comparable airplane fuselage, but around 10 tons based on a comparable ISS module (Destiny...).
- What would be the cost to build such pressure vessel ? If I make a rule-of-thumb made on pressurized aircraft, it looks like this would cost a few million dollars (2-5). Probably, space-grade stuff is more expensive
- what rocket can I use to send around 10 tons to the moon surface ? I understand I should take a rocket with around 70 tons capacity to low-earth orbit, like Falcon Heavy would be OK.

I would be glad to get your advice.

Comment: Would worldbuilding stack exchange be a better fit for this?

Comment: Repost your question on worldbuilding stack exchange. 
https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/